# Delivering Oracle functions within app and they are not compiled

Tags: oracle, function, oracle10g

Within an application I am passing embedded SQL to an Oracle 10g instance, which creates a function using the schema owner creds.  The function is properly created but not compiled.  I can compile it manually outside of the app, using the same creds the app used.  Any ideas why delivered functions would not automatically compile if they are syntactically correct and user is the schema owner?

Comment: **Read tag descriptions before adding!**

Comment: can you please update your question to provide an example of a) the kind of function you're trying to create and b) how you're passing it across and c) what do you mean by "created but not compiled"? Do you get errors for that function as shown in user_errors? N.B. in general, it's very insecure for an application to connect to the database using the same schema that the database objects reside in. You've basically given the application carte blanche to do anything. Such as drop tables - sound like a good idea to you?

Comment: What is the status of the function after it is created, in `all_objects`? Are there any issues reported in `all_errors`? Does the call to create the function return an exception - and how is it called, and where from? The function will be compiled when it is created, but the compilation may fail; though it then doesn't really make sense that you can compile it with the same credentials. There may be something about the set-up that you haven't told us.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out.  We were embedding Carriage Returns and Line Feeds in the string containing the "create function" being sent to Oracle.  We do this so when we spit out the SQL in an error handler it is pretty!  I removed the CR and just left the LF and it parsed and compiled just fine.  I am suspect that when I copy pasted the creation function from a watch variable into SQL Developer the CR was getting removed or the IDE is more tolerant.